# Left and right topological K-theory of Banach algebras

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let us consider the topological $K$-functor on the category of Banach algebras as described [in page $18$](https://books.google.com/books?id=wX8ECAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18) of *"Introduction to the Baum–Connes conjecture"* by Alain Valette.
The definition is based on invertible groups $\mathrm{GL}_n(A)$where $A$ is a Banach algebra.

> What would we obtain if we replace these invertible groups with the space (semigroup) of right or left invertible matrices? Is the resulting structures somehow the same as standard $k$ groups defined with  full invertible group $\mathrm{GL}_n(A)$?

The motivation comes from the following situation: 
One can find  in the literature the concepts left and right topological stable rank which are based on left or right invertibility of a certain element $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_i^*$ associated to an $n$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ in a $C^*$-algebra. With this motivation we try to consider the left and right K-theories on category of Banach algebras. Does this trivially leads us to the standard K-theory?